# JavaScript object declaration syntax - variable names as properties

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

JavaScript gives you a lot of ways to declare objects. When you have most of the data available at hand, the most convenient (in my opinion) is as follows:

```
var person = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 23
}; // "object literal syntax"
```

A curious thing about this syntax is that it is identical to this:

```
var person = {
    'name': 'John',
    'age': 23
}; // "object literal syntax"
```

That is, you can use quotes or omit them for the property names.

When comparing that to the way setting a single property works, you have two options:

```
person.birthday = "January 12"; // "dot syntax"
```

or

```
person['birthday'] = "January 12"; // "array syntax"
```

The "dot syntax" only works when the right operand is the actual property name. If you want to use a variable for the property name, you have to use "array syntax", i.e.:

```
var prop = "birthday";
person[prop] = "January 12";
```

Now, is it possible to use a variable for the property name in the "object literal syntax"? Since it doesn't matter if you quote the property names, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to use a variable there. I'm looking for something like this:

```
var prop = "birthday";
var person = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 23,
    (prop): 'January 12'
};
```

Here I'm using (prop) as the imaginary syntax used to express that this is a variable and not a literal string.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll have to stick to the array syntax.. maybe eval('person.'+prop+' = "January 12"') will do the trick, but I don't think this is the optimal solution

Comment: @PhilippeBoissonneault -- Ack!  Eval is *not* needed... please don't use it in this context.

Comment: You're looking for the equivalent of the PHP variable variables:  `$foo = bar; $bar = '123'; echo $$foo;// actually displays '123'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable for a Javascript object key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES6 now allows for this:

```
var obj = {
  [prop]: 'value'
};
```

Answer (score 7):

No, this will not work, that is why, if you are dynamically setting property names, array like notation is suggested and used.

```
var k='propertyname';
object[k]="value";
```

this works while using the dot notation to set index or property name from vatiable is not possible.

Comment: I believe the phrase `bracket notation` is preferred, but otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 4):

For people who need a drop-in replacement for dot syntax where the keys are objects instead of strings (say for nesting inside a parent Object), here are some workarounds:

```
var developers = {
    person: {
        'name': 'John',
        'age': 23
    },
    anarchist: (function(){ var a = {};
        a['name'] = 'John';
        a['age'] = 23;
        a[false] = false;
        a[1] = 1;
        a[window] = window;
    return a; })(),
    conformist: _.object([
        ['name', 'John'],
        ['age', 23],
        [false, false],
        [1, 1],
        [window, window]
    ])
};

// console.log(developers); // <- to see var dump in Firebug
```

The anarchist element uses a [self-executing-function](http://www.jspatterns.com/self-executing-functions/) that gets garbage collected after the call, and the conformist element uses the [_.object()](http://underscorejs.org/#object) function if you can include underscore.js in your site.

I wish that the built-in Object() and Array() functions allowed for passing in keys and values the way underscore.js does it :-)

Comment: a drop in self-calling functions is def my preferred solution +1

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this with objects, but if you consider using a constructor function instead, it could look something like this:

```
var prop = "birthday";
var Person = function() {
    this.name = "Bob";
    this[prop] = "January 12";
};
var bob = new Person();
```

Of course you still have the array notation here, but maybe you like this aproach anyway :)