# Get Variable working inside method

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, methods

how do I get the value of the variable "lastColnum" working inside "headers:"?

lastColnum has the value for disabling the last column of the html table.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 

    var numCols = $("#customer").find('tr')[0].cells.length;
    var lastColnum = numCols-1;

        $("#kundentable").tablesorter({

            headers: { 

            0: { 
                sorter: false 
            },
            lastColnum: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            }
        } 
    }); 
    } 
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript object declaration syntax - variable names as properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607845/javascript-object-declaration-syntax-variable-names-as-properties)

Comment: This has nothing to do with being inside a method. The problem is that you are trying to use a variable as a property name in an object literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this dynamically:

```
var tsData = {
    headers: { 
      0: { 
          sorter: false 
         }
      } 
};
tsData.headers[lastColnum] = { sorter: false }
$("#kundentable").tablesorter(tsData);
```