# How to append object value using for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I loop through an array called accData and make a new array called WL and RF. I want to make it easy to maintain, but I have a problem. When I want to change the WL array data to CH2 and RF array data to DIG2, I have to type the script manually.
This is my script

```
const accData = [
    { st: 'serijabo', path: 'serijabo.json', wl: 'CH1', rf: 'DIG1' },
    { st: 'sukabumi', path: 'sukabumi.json', wl: 'CH2', rf: 'DIG2' },
];

for (let i = 0; i < accData.length; i++) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    let WL = [];
    let RF = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      WL.push(Number(data[i].CH1)); // this line
      RF.push(Number(data[i].DIG1)); // and this line
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I try to use ES6 template to solve it but it is not working because the template must be place in a string.

```
WL.push(Number(data[i].`${accData[i].wl}`)); //not working
RF.push(Number(data[i].`${accData[i].rf}`)); //not working
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is that `Number()` really necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript object declaration syntax - variable names as properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607845/javascript-object-declaration-syntax-variable-names-as-properties)

Comment: yes, because json returns string and i want to process number, so i convert it @Vilx-

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043026/variable-as-the-property-name-in-a-javascript-object-literal and so many hundreds of other questions about the same thing.

Comment: You use `i` twice.... That is your major issue

Comment: In javascript, there's a subtle difference between `number` and `Number`. I suggest using `parseInt()` instead. That will do what you think it does.

Comment: Or `parseFloat()`, if you're dealing with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using brackets instead of a dot? They should allow you to access properties via a string.

```
WL.push(Number(data[i][`${accData[i].wl}`]));
RF.push(Number(data[i][`${accData[i].rf}`]));
```

Comment: Also `i` has been redefined in the callback.

Comment: Not to mention the whole string expression is totally unnecesary. Just do `data[i][accData[i].rf]`

Comment: the `data[i][accData[i].wl]` returns error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wl' of undefined" while the `data[i].CH1` works fine

Comment: If you're getting that error it means the object `accData[i]` doesn't exist at some moment for you to access its `wl` property. You can write ```accData[i] && WL.push(Number(data[i][`${accData[i].wl}`]));``` so the code will only run when `accData[i]` exists.

Comment: and the `(data[i]['{accData[i].wl}'])` returns NaN for every element

Comment: You're typecasting the value of `(data[i]['{accData[i].wl}'])` to number in your code, if the value is something that can't be parsed as number then `Number()` will return `NaN` (not a number).

Comment: In fact, `CH1`, `CH2`, `DIG1` and `DIG2` are values that can't be parsed directly to a number. If you want to get just the number part you'll have to clean these values, you could use a regular expression for that.

Comment: You can do `Number((data[i]['{accData[i].wl}']).replace(/\D/g,''))`, which will only typecast your string to number after all non-digit values have been removed.

Comment: first thank you for your respons, but i do not understand because i can get the number part when parsing json value using `data[i].CH1`.  And i've tried the `accData[i] && WL.push(Number(data[i][`${accData[i].wl}`]));`, it returns only the last element of json not combine all the elements.

Comment: `data[i].CH1` is a value that comes from your API's response, right? It probably comes as a number or a string containing only digits, so that's why it works. In your `accData` object, the values for `wl` are either `CH1` and `CH2`, which are strings containing not only numbers, but characters as well.

Comment: I'm still confused, the `WL.push(Number(data[i]['CH1']));` works fine, but `WL.push(Number(data[i]['accData[i].wl']));` returns `NaN`, while `'accData[i].wl'` returns `CH1`. I'm using the same url but returns different result. Do you have an example or an article about this topic? I want to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you writing ```data[i][`${accData[i].wl}`]``` or ```data[i]['accData[i].wl'])```? Because those are very different things.

Comment: when I write ``accData[i] && WL.push(Number(data[i][`${accData[i].wl}`]));`` it returns only the first CH1 value, not all of them

Comment: I get a clue when the ``accData[i] && WL.push(Number(data[i][`${accData[i].wl}`]));`` returns only the first CH1 value, so I set another for loop to return all CH1 value. @TelmoTrooper.